# Rank users based on test score and time

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following model: (simplified)

```
class TestResults(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    test = models.ForeignKey(Test)
    score = models.FloatField()
    time = models.FloatField()
    # ... more fields
```

I want to get a list of `TestResult` that is about a certain `test`, filter out those with 0 scores, take the best result each user got, and sort all the results from best to worst. Best is defined as having the highest score, and if the score is the same, the least time.

I have not been able to find a sane solution with models and querysets that does it in one query.

Currently, I am using this raw SQL (simplified) after trying for days without any other solution:

```
SELECT res.id, res.user_id, res.test_id, res.score, res.time, res.more_fields...
FROM (
    SELECT user_id, MAX(score) AS score
    FROM app_testresult
    WHERE test_id = %s AND score > 0
    GROUP BY user_id
) AS highscore INNER JOIN (
    SELECT user_id, score, MIN(time) as time
    FROM app_testresult
    WHERE test_id = %s
    GROUP BY user_id, score
) AS fastest
        ON (highscore.user_id = fastest.user_id AND highscore.score = fastest.score)
    INNER JOIN app_testresult as res
        ON (res.user_id = fastest.user_id AND res.time = fastest.time)
GROUP BY fastest.user_id
ORDER BY res.score DESC, res.time ASC
```

The thought of this SQL makes me cringe, but I can't find any other solution.

My configuration:

- Django version: 1.6.7
- Database: MySQL 5.5